# ¿Cómo detener scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

Os explico: Tengo que leer un programa de entrenamiento de 10 días, con un máximo de 1000 caracteres para la descripción de cada uno de los días de entrenamiento.

El problema que tengo es que si introduzco más de 1000 caracteres el programa sigue leyendo con scanf ej.

```
Día 1: Correr.
Día 2: Andar.... (+1000 caracteres)
Día 3: Correr ( y después me mete el resto de los más de 1000 caracteres que no ha podido meter en el día 2.
```

Se que en otros lenguajes hay posibilidades, pero en este no soy capaz de hacerlo. ¿alguna pista?

Hasta aquí el módulo que he codificado:

```
/**********************************************
* Módulo: Entrenamiento
*
* Este módulo contiene las funciones que
* permiten guardar y listar el entrenamiento
**********************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include "entre.h"

/*-------------- Elementos privados -----------------*/

const int LINEA = 1000; /* número máximo de caracteres */
const int DIAS = 10; /* número de días de entrenamiento */

typedef char tablaEnt[DIAS][LINEA];

static tablaEnt tabla;
static int dia;
static int longitud;
static char tecla;

/*-------------- Elementos públicos ----------------*/

void IniciarTabla() {
   for (int i = 0; i<DIAS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<LINEA; j++) {
      tabla[i][j] = ' ';
    }
  }
}

void IntroRutina() {
  dia = 0;
  do {
    printf( "Actividad del dia %d? ", dia+1);
    scanf( " %c", &tecla );
    longitud = 0;
    while (tecla != '\n') {
      tabla[dia][longitud] = tecla;
      longitud++;
      scanf( "%c", &tecla );
      }
    }
    dia++;
  } while (dia<DIAS);
  printf( "\n" );
}

void ListarRutina() {

  for (int i = 0; i<DIAS; i++) {
    printf( "Dia %d\n", i+1);
    if (i+1<10) {
      printf( "=====\n" );
    } else {
      printf ( "======\n" );
    }
    for (int j = 0; j<LINEA; j++) {
      printf( "%c", tabla[i][j] );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
  }
    printf( "\n\n" );
}
```

Comment: ¿Que lenguaje estas usando? seria recomendable que coloques como tag al lenguaje de programacion.

Comment: @eyllanesc no tengo la opción. C+- es una mezcla entre c y c++

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto puede ser util para ti. Dentro del formato del `scanf`, hay una opcion poco conocida que te permite leer de la misma forma cierta informacion pero sin guardarla. Por ejemplo, si lees tres enteros pero solamente te interesan el primero y el ultimo, puedes hacerlo asi:

```
scanf("%d%*d%d", &a, &b, &c);
```

Todo esta en agregarle el `*` antes del especificador de conversión. A lo que quiero llegar con esto es que si luego de leer los caracteres teniendo en cuenta la longitud máxima, logras comprobar que ya has llegado, entonces necesitas obviar todos los caracteres hasta el proximo fin de línea. Esto lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
if (dia >= DIAS) {
    scanf("%*[^\n]");
}
```

Te explico lo que hace. Por ejemplo, al escribir `scanf("%[abc]", x)`, el programa va a leer y a guardar en `x` todos los caracteres `a`, `b`, o `c` consecutivos que encuentre, porque estan dentro de ese conjunto. Puedes especificar tambien que quieres guardar los que `NO` estan en el conjunto agregando el circunflejo `^` delante. Ejemplo:

```
scanf("%[^0123456789]", x);
```

Esto va a leer todos los caracteres que se encuentre hasta que llegue a un digito, debido a que especificamos que dentro de `x` se va a guardar cualquier cosa diferente de un digito. Similar pasa con el codigo de arriba. Estas leyendo todos los caracteres hasta que te encuentres con un fin de linea pero como tiene el asterisco delante, simplemente no se guardan. Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Isaac, creo que estoy avanzando con esto que me has dicho.

Comment: @DIEGOALONSO: Si te fue util y es la respuesa que soluciona tu problema por favor, marcala como tal para que otros que tengan la intencion de ayudar no pierdan su tiempo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Noto que el programa lee carácter a carácter de lo que ingrese el usuario, y si este se equivoca y quiere corregir puede ocurrir un problema o ni siquiera ser capaz de borrar el error. 
Te propongo que cambies la función IntroRutina() utilizando fgets() en lugar de scanf().

Los parámetros de fgets() son tres: 
 
fgets( [Una variable donde guardar lo que se introduce de tipo char *], [Un número límite de carácteres recibidos de tipo entero], [De donde se toman los datos])

El primero es fácil, crear una variable. La llamaré actividad. 
El segundo ya lo mencionaste, pues solo quieres 1000. 
El tercero se debe a que fgets puede leer incluso de ficheros u otros archivos, pero como queremos de la consola debes poner *stdin*.

Este es el cambio que propongo:

```
void IntroRutina() {
  char *actividad;
  dia = 0;
  longitud = 0;
  do {
    printf( "Actividad del dia %d? ", dia+1);
    fgets(actividad, 1000, stdin);
    tabla[dia][longitud] = actividad;
    longitud++;
    dia++;
  } while (dia<DIAS);
}
```

fgets también coge el "\n", pero lo puedes eliminar con una función extra como esta:

```
void QuitarEspacio(char *str) {
  int j=0;    //Servirá como salida alternativa del bucle
  for (int i=0; i<1000 && j == 0; i++){
      if (str[i] == '\n'){
         str[i] = '\0';    //Si la posición i tiene '/n', entonces la cambia por nulo
         j=1;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: No puedo usar fgets en la asignatura y con el lenguaje que estoy trabajando... Pero gracias igualmente

Answer (score 0):

`scanf( )` tiene un *modificador* para indicar **el tamaño máximo** de los datos a leer:

```
char buf[20];
scanf( "%19s", buf );
```

Con lo anterior, se leen solamente `19` caracteres.

**No olvidemos** que se coloca un `'\0'` **después** del último carácter, por lo que nuestro *buffer* **ha de tener 1 espacio más** del necesario.